# Do callback functions block the main thread when using socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, socket.io

Im trying to build my server in node.js. Im using socket.io.

Something similiar to this:

```js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

I know that IO in node.js is asynchronous, but if i call a function in 'on connection' like reading a file, would it still be asynchronous or would it block the main thread? Im not sure, my understading ist that everything that is called inside the asynchronous IO is also runned asynchronous without blocking the main thread.

Comment: *I know that IO in node.js is asynchronous* Why do you know this? You have to explicitly call the async version of the I/O method you want. It's not automatic.

Comment: It still runs on the single "main" thread (and would block it) - it just runs *later* (that's what *a*synchrony means).

Comment: Is it then even possible to write a good node.js server that can handle a lot of traffic? Just as an example 1000 user requests ata time?

Comment: @Olli — Yes. Just don't do expensive blocking operations (like synchronous file system access).

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous code is code which *runs later* instead of blocking while it waits for something.

The connection event handler is asynchronous. It won't run until the event happens (so it won't block everything else while waiting for the event to happen).

The function you call will be called just like any other function. It will block while it is running. If it is an asynchronous function, it will stop running and wait for whatever it is waiting for without blocking.

e.g.

`readFileSync` will block while the file is being read (it won't block until you call it, which won't happen until the event happens).

`readFile` won't block, at least not in a significant way. It will occupy the main thread while it sets up the file read, then sleep (without blocking) until the file data is available, at which point it will wake up again and pass the result to the callback.

Comment: Now i got it, i thought it would run parallel. Is it possible to do things parallel or someting like that? In Java u could use a lot of threads but Javascript-node.js is limited.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nodejs+threads gives https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html as the first hit.